# Meaning of the saying 逢着天门

Tags: translation

逢着天门 Does anyone know the meaning of this saying or idiom? It is part of the commentary to a Shenshu verse, which doesn't really make sense to me, but it seems this expression more or less explains the verse.

Comment: `逢着` during the time.,  `天门` a mythical occasion similar to "constellations arrangement".   So `逢着天门` simply mean `during specific constellations arrangement`.

Answer (score 1):

The full sentence goes like this:"去到长安，东北转角，逢着天门，便有下落", comes from Zhuge Shenshu Verse No.355. If you feel it doesn't make sense, then you get the point. This book was used to do Fortune-telling, so it meant to confuse the readers, so the  Fortune-tellers can pick up from here, use their knowledge (verbal tricks) to explain your destiny.
A word to word translation: "Go to Chang An (The Capital City), north east corner, Meet Tianmen (Can be explained into a certain place or a certain time), then you find it."

Answer (score 0):

web search：http://blog.sina.cn/dpool/blog/s/blog_5607e12b0100ar1k.html
esp. 光有地理位置还不够，还必须掌握时间，才能组成一个有效的时空坐标（space-time coordinates），逢着天门，就是指时间而言，让我们看奇门遁甲，上怎么说。
奇门遁甲 bkrs：the art of becoming invisible -- Daoist magic